# positive semidefiniteness: a psd matrix substracted by another rank 1 psd matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

Given that $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, $x$ is a vector, $\lambda_0 \in [0, +\infty) $ is a real non-negative number. I want to know the answer to the following optimization problem.

$$
\arg \min_{\lambda} |\lambda- \lambda_0| \\
s.t. \;\;  A-\lambda xx^T \ge 0
$$

Note $A-\lambda xx^T \ge 0$ means that $A-\lambda xx^T$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: The set $\{\lambda: A \ge \lambda xx^T \}$ is an interval of the form $(-\infty,\lambda_1]$ where $\lambda_1\ge 0$. Hence, $\arg \min_{\lambda} |\lambda- \lambda_0| $ is  $\min(\lambda_0, \lambda_1)$. So the real question is how to find $\lambda_1$.

Answer (score 2):

The required minimiser is $\min(\lambda_0,\lambda_1)$, where $\lambda_1 = \max\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}: A-\lambda xx^T\succeq0\}$. So, the problem boils down to finding $\lambda_1$.

Let $Q$ be a real orthogonal matrix whose first column is $x/\|x\|$ and let $B=Q^TAQ$. Then the constraint $A-\lambda xx^T\succeq0$ is equivalent to $B-\lambda\|x\|^2E_{11}\succeq0$, where $E_{11}$ is the matrix with a $1$ at the $(1,1)$-th entry and zeroes elsewhere. Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, this constraint can be further transformed (by orthogonal similarity) into the form of
$$
\pmatrix{a-\lambda\|x\|^2 & v^T & u^T\\ v&D&0\\ u&0&0} \succeq 0
$$
where $a=x^TAx/\|x\|^2$ and $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Note that $u$ is necessarily zero because $B$ is positive semidefinite. Therefore, the above constraint is equivalent to
$$
M=\pmatrix{a-\lambda\|x\|^2 & v^T\\ v&D} \succeq 0.
$$
As $D$ is positive definite, $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\det(M)\ge0$. Using Schur complement, we get $\det(M)=\det(D)(a-\lambda\|x\|^2-v^TD^{-1}v)$. Therefore
$$\lambda_1 = \frac1{\|x\|^2} (a - v^TD^{-1}v).$$

Comment: Very detailed derivation here. Two things I cannot follow. 1. You claim that $A-\lambda xx^T \ge 0$ is equivalent to $B-\lambda \|x\|^2 E_{11} \ge 0$. So you are trying to say that, given a psd matrix $M$ and a orthogonal matrix $O$, $M \ge 0$ is equivalent to $O^TMO \ge 0$. Can you show this to me? 2. You are claiming $u$ is necessarily zero because $B$ is psd. Why?

Comment: @Shaohua 1. Actually $M\succeq0$ iff $P^TMP\succeq0$ for any invertible matrix $P$. It is easy to prove that if you consider $x^TP^TMPx$. 2. If $u\neq0$, then for sufficiently large $c>0$ and $x^T=(1,0,-cv^T)$, we have $x^TMx<0$.

Comment: Can you further explain "Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, this constraint can be further transformed (by orthogonal similarity) "? How do you perform this transformation to have the new equivalent form?

Comment: Yes. What I don't understand is what $v$ and $u$ and $D$ stands for here.

Comment: Very nice demonstration. One last thing I am still unclear of: $B-\lambda\|x\|^2E_{11}$ is a $n \cdot n$ matrix, but $\pmatrix{a-\lambda\|x\|^2 & v^T & u^T\\ v&D&0\\ u&0&0} $ is $(n+1) \cdot (n+1)$. How come this is true? I have come up with a solution myself, which is given below.

Comment: @Shawn No. It is $n\times n$. Let $B=\pmatrix{b_{11}&\ast\\ \ast&C_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}}$. As $C$ is symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalised by some orthogonal matrix $P_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$, so that $P^TCP=\pmatrix{D&0\\ 0&0}$ is an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ diagonal matrix (with the three zero blocks having appropriate sizes) and $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Now the first displayed matrix is the result of $\pmatrix{1\\ &P^T}B\pmatrix{1\\ &P}$.

Answer (score 0):

By Schur's Complement, $A-\lambda xx^T\succeq0$ is equivalent to
$ \pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}&x^T\\ x& A} \ge 0 $.

$ \pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}&x^T\\ x& A} $ can be diagonalized as
$ \pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x  &0\\ 0& A} $.

$ \pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x  &0\\ 0& A} \ge0$ iff $\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x \ge0$ and $A \ge0$.

Now it is clear that $\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x \ge0$ or

$\lambda \le (x^TA^{-1}x)^{-1}$

should be the answer to this problem.

Comment: This is not correct. How do you diagonalise $\pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}&x^T\\ x& A}$ to $\pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x  &0\\ 0& A}$? If $x\neq0$ and $A$ is positive definite, it can be shown that what you have stated here can never happen.

Comment: You may, however, consider the Schur complement of $A$, so that $\det\pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}&x^T\\ x^T&A}=\det(A)(\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x)$. When $A\succ0$, this gives rise to the condition that $\lambda^{-1}>x^TA^{-1}x$.

Comment: $\pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}&x^T\\ x& A} = \pmatrix{1&x^TA^{-1}\\ 0& I} \pmatrix{\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x  &0\\ 0& A} \pmatrix{1&x^TA^{-1}\\ 0& I}^T$.

Comment: Now this is valid and this is actually how Schur complement is derived. ("Diagonalisation" usually means diagonalisation via similarity. Yours is block diagonalisation via congruence.) Note that your answer is still problematic in two aspects: (1) $\lambda^{-1}-x^TA^{-1}x\ge0$ is **not** equivalent to $\lambda\le x^TA^{-1}x$. (2) Your question states that $A$ is positive semidefinite, so $A^{-1}$ does not always exist.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly as you said.